# trim the trailing space and show placeholder when there is no visible input - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Consider the following input

```
<input ng-if="isRequired()"
       type="text"
       name="{{fieldNamePrefix}}[name]"
       ng-value="orderCommodity.name"
       class="form-control top15"
       ng-disabled="disabled"
       placeholder="CERTIFICATION" />
```

Now consider that that the user enters a space and moves to the next field. I need to trim that space and show the placeholder again since there is no visible input.

I have tried **ng-trim** but doesn't seem to work. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom directive. It triggers on blur and checks input value. If it contains only spaces then it will empty the value. Note that you will need to use `ng-model` instead of `ng-value`:

```
myApp.directive('trimDir', function() {
    return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

      element.bind('blur', function(e) {
        console.log(ctrl)
        let trimmed = ctrl.$viewValue.replace(/[\s]/g, '');
        if (trimmed.length == 0) {
          ctrl.$setViewValue('');
          ctrl.$render();
        }
      });
    }
  };

})
```

And in html:

```
<input type="text" 
       name="name" 
       ng-model="orderCommodity.name" 
       class="form-control top15" 
       placeholder="CERTIFICATION" 
       trim-dir />
```

Check a working demo here: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zdbfvta8/27/)

Comment: is it possible to make this directive functional by using ng-value instead of ng-model?

Comment: No, I don't think it can work with `ng-value` (which has one-way binding). In a non-angular way, using element to get value etc, it might work but I wouldn't suggest that. Can't you use `ng-model` ?